# DB2 9.7 statement vs row triggers

Tags: triggers, db2

I have tried to find the difference between row and statement triggers for DB2, but I still don't quite get it :) If I have a case that for every updated column in a specific table, the name of the column is logged in another LOG table row. So if I use a row trigger, then for every row in a transaction where that table row is updated, the trigger is initiated. In a statement trigger, if 10 rows are updated for that table, the update trigger is initiated only once? If so, does the statement trigger still behave in the same way as the row trigger, only more optimal?

In a row trigger, I understand that accessing the DELETED or INSERTED parameters I can get a pointer to the updated row. But what about statement trigger? Does the DELETED and INSERTED parameters contain a list of all rows for a particular column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the section in the Information Center on [designing triggers](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0020225.html).

In this section, you'll find information on when a [trigger fires](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0020227.html),

> When a trigger is activated, it runs according to its level of
>   granularity as follows:
>
> **FOR EACH ROW**
>
> It runs as many times as the number of rows in the set of affected rows. If you need to refer to the specific rows affected by the
>   triggered action, use FOR EACH ROW granularity. An example of this is
>   the comparison of the new and old values of an updated row in an AFTER
>   UPDATE trigger.
>
> **FOR EACH STATEMENT**
>
> It runs once for the entire trigger event.
>
> If the set of affected rows is empty (that is, in the case of a
>   searched UPDATE or DELETE in which the WHERE clause did not qualify
>   any rows), a FOR EACH ROW trigger does not run. But a FOR EACH
>   STATEMENT trigger still runs once.

You'll also see how to access old and new data either [by row](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0020235.html), or the full [table at once](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0020236.html).